# Hibernate - Save Child if not persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, duplicates, unique

i have a threading hibernate problem.
I have a ManyToOne Relation with a track whitch include two city objects.
Through the thread it is possible that my trackDao get many trackEntitys to persist witch include the same city (zipcode is unique).

After the trackDao persist the first entity i get a "duplicate entity exception".

Is it possible to configure via annotaition to force a get bevore save to get the existing childId and resume parrent persisting?

Thx

---

thx for your time.

I try a manual get before i try to save a city to get a possibly already existing city (with the same zipcode) from db.

Now a trip includes two cities. 
One city witch is allready stored in db (objectId != null)
and an other city witch have to get persist (objectId == null)

Although hibernate now have to know that city1 is already persist an only city2 have to get persist in city- table i get a "duplicate entity exception". Hibernate will store the existing city again.
To slove that I overrive the generic save method of my tripDao and handle the city persisting manual. -> just save city if city.getId() == null.
So I get a not stored trip object witch includes two already stored citys. If i try to persist that trip object I get the hibernate message

"Error while persist trackjavax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: de....CityEntity"

I belive I had something configured totaly wrong.

Pls help.

I dont want to overrive the save method and store realations manualy. In my opinion that have to works by default, or not?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tracks", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "city1_id", "city2_id" }))
@SessionScoped
public class TrackEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4696847902782174082L;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CityEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="city1_id")
    private CityEntity city1;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CityEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="city2_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private CityEntity city2;

    private Integer distance;





@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
@SessionScoped
public class CityEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8823384603378561475L;

    private String name;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String zipcode;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
```

Comment: Can you post some code? What primary keys you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think a track has two identical city . I had a same problem with Order ->* Product. But this was a bug in application where a Order can not have duplicate product. I don't know what is allowed in your case but I suggest you to Investigate City class and look for equals method. If you have java.util.List in Track class to hold cities then it is possible that that list have two element of same object (==).